# Zel'dovich pancake derivation

Tags: cosmology, gravity, resource-recommendations, stability

I am looking for a derivation of the Zel'dovich pancake. Does anyone have a reference to the derivation or a link to the original paper?

Y. Zel'dovich, *Gravitational instability: An Approximate theory for large density perturbations* https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1970A%26A.....5...84Z https://inspirehep.net/literature/55133